# Facebook Open Graph not showing on timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, fb-graph

I'm using FB Open Graph in my application.  It's not fully working.  When I post a object it appears in the user's recent activity; however, it doesn't appear on their timeline.  The metadata has no errors and I'm using the FBGraph gem but it also doesn't work when I do it using curl.  Any advise to fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried to use 'fb:explicitly_shared=true' in your URL. Refer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/explicit-sharing/

Comment: i wish i found this answer 8 hours ago.

Comment: I also wish like you :D. Lost 8 hours for this.

Comment: I saw that thinking it was based on privacy, but I see now this is really about how visible the post is. Privacy being separate. Little confusing, but sure glad I found this. Also to others reading this in your app settings under open graph / types / actions you can set Explicitly Shared under advanced section

Comment: OMG typo on explicit[e]ly kept my test posts from showing up for 4 days

Answer (score 1):

When you are in development mode, and your actions have not yet been approved by Facebook, the posted actions are only visible to you and to others with developer, admin or tester privileges for your FB app.

See: [Facebook action submission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/opengraph-tutorial/#submit)

Also, open graph actions will no longer appear in users' news feeds or even the Ticker: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/398546930211799/. So you shouldn't expect activities performed in your app to appear in users' timelines, unless these activities are tagged as 'explicitly shared', and even then there's no guarantee they'll show up.

Only direct, active shares are more or less guaranteed to show up in the Timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Did you submit your action  to get approved by facebook? If you did not do this, it will only work on your facebook account.

Also, are you sure you request the correct permission when the user authenticates, such as 'publish_stream'?

Comment: I haven't submitted it but I was using my account.  We do have publish_stream permissions.

Comment: FYI: It should be 'publish_actions' not 'publish_stream' More: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/