# Open Graph - how to make published action appear on timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I publish actions from by website using the app I created for it on facebook.

My actions have been approved by FB.

when they are published they appear on the activity log.

However they do not appear on the timeline and do not show on the main pages of that user's friends, only under activity log.

How can I make it so the actions are posted to the timeline itself and all the user's friends would see it on the main page?

Thank you

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800466/facebook-open-graph-not-showing-on-timeline ?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [Explicit Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/explicit-sharing/). Just Open Graph by itself doesn't guarantee your content will be pushed into News Feed and/or Timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly_shared on its own does not always seem to be effective.

I have experienced this myself (and still do), where although the "explicitly_shared" attribute is set to "true", the post does not show up on timeline.

On checking the activilty log, is is marked as "allowed on timeline" but not "shown on timeline", which seems to need to be set manually and results in the correct post. I presume there is a way to force this, but I have not yet found it!

(the app is approved and live, with publish_actions enabled)